# How to vectorize with mismatched dimensionality

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I have some constraints of the form of

`A_{i,j,k} = r_{i,j}B_{i,j,k}`

`A` is a `nxmxp` matrix, as is B. `r` is an `nxm` matrix.

I would like to vectorize this in Python somehow, as efficiently as possible. Right now, I am making `r` into `nxmxp` matrix by saying `r_{i,j,k} = r_{i,j} for all 1 <= k <= p`. Then I call `np.multiply` on `r` and `B`. This seems inefficient. Any ideas welcome, thanks.

```py
def ndHadamardProduct(r, n, m, p): #r is a n x m matrix, p is an int
    rnew = np.zeros(n, m, p)
    B = np.zeros(n, m, p)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            for k in range(p):
                r[i, j, k] = r[i, j]
                B[i, j, k] = random.uniform(0, 1)
    return np.multiply(r, B)
```

Comment: Please post your code, and outputs.

Comment: A minimal example would be more helpful, but I'm guessing you want `np.einsum('ij,ijk->ijk', r, B)`

Comment: Is np.einsum more efficient than using [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) with `R[:, :, np.newaxis] * B`?

Comment: @KoenG. in this case, there will be virtually no difference in performance between the two, broadcasting will probably be a tiny bit faster.

Comment: Basic rule of `broadcasting` - explicitly add trailing dimensions as needed, leading ones are added automatically.  All size 1 dimensions are adjusted to match the other arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra dimension with `np.newaxis` and then [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) takes care of the repetition for you.

```py
import numpy as np
r = np.random.random((3,4))
b = np.random.random((3,4,5))
a = r[:,:,np.newaxis] * b
```